# How can I install flashtext on every executor?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am using the flashtext library in a couple of UDFs. It works when I run it locally in Client mode, but once I try to run it in the Cloudera Workbench with several executors, I get an `ModuleNotFoundError`.
After some research I found that it is possible to add archives (and packages?) to a SparkSession when creating it, so I tried:

```
SparkSession.builder.config('spark.archives', 'flashtext-2.7-pyh9f0a1d_0.tar.gz')
```

but it didn't help, the same error remains.
According to [Spark Configuration doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), there are other configs I could try, e.g. `spark.submit.pyFiles`, but I don't understand how these py-files to be added would have to look like.
Would it be enough to just create a pyton script with this content?

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
```

Could you tell me the easiest way how I can install flashtext on every node?

Edit:
In the meantime, I figured that not only Flashtext was causing issues, but also every relative import from other scripts that I intended to use in a UDF. In order to fix it, I followed this [article](https://janetvn.medium.com/how-to-add-multiple-python-custom-modules-to-spark-job-6a8b943cdbbc). I also took the source code from Flashtext and imported it to the main file without installing the actual library.

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to point Spark executors to python modules extracted from your archive, you will need to add another config setting, that adds their location to  `PYTHONPATH`. Something like this:

```
SparkSession.builder \
  .config('spark.archives', 'flashtext-2.7-pyh9f0a1d_0.tar.gz#myUDFs') \
  .config('spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH', './myUDFs')
```

Citing from the same link you have in the question:

> spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]
> ...
> Add the environment
> variable specified by EnvironmentVariableName to the Executor process.
> The user can specify multiple of these to set multiple environment
> variables.

There are no environment details in your question (or I'm simply not familiar with Cloudera Workbench) but if you're trying to run Spark on YARN, you may need to use slightly different setting [`spark.yarn.dist.archives`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).

Also, please make sure that your driver log contains message confirming that an archive was actually uploaded, as in:

```
:
22/11/08 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/absolute/path/to/your/archive.zip -> hdfs://nameservice/user/<your-user-id>/.sparkStaging/<application-id>/archive.zip
:
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I still get the same error. Do you have an idea how the files need to look like which I can add with 'spark.submit.pyFIles'?

Comment: sorry to hear that. AFAIK there is no special requirements, and as parameter description says any _".zip, .egg, or .py files to place on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps"_ will be uploaded into Spark staging dir. Maybe repackaging .tar.gz into a simple .zip worth a shot.